# Self Join : How to select a specific set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with data as

[image]

As we can see that row 1 & 2 contains exact same ColumnA, ColumnB & ColumnC. I want to form a simple select that can ignore the 'N' values where we already have a yes, so something like

[image]

I tried using self join but guess not using it right or likely not using the right thing.

Can someone drop a little suggestion here?

This is what I am trying

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    [Table] AS main 
    INNER JOIN [Table] AS sub ON
        sub.columna = main.columna
        and
        sub.columnb = main.columnb
        and
        sub.columnc = main.columnc
WHERE
    -- This is where I am struggling to add a condition:
    ((main.columnd = 'Y'
    AND
    sub.columnd = 'Y')
    OR
    (main.columnd = 'N'
    AND
    sub.columnd = 'Y'))
```

Comment: FYI can you post sample data and expected results as formatted text rather than images. And if you provide DDL/DML statements you'll encourage people to help you faster.

Comment: oh. I tried. for some reason the editor is not letting me drop text. Let me try and edit this again

Comment: I think you just need to add some parentheses to your `WHERE` clause. Don't mix `AND` and `OR` at the same level in a predicate.

Comment: I expect you want to add some brackets to your where clause e.g. `(main.columnd = 'Y' AND sub.columnd = 'Y' OR (main.columnd = 'N' AND sub.columnd = 'Y'))`

Comment: I recommend reading [operator-precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Dai Thanks. I Do have brackets as dale suggested but i still get all four rows back instead of three. So i am guessing the condition I am putting is not right. I am looking to ignore the rows where (when ColumnA to C are the same and we have a 'Y' in ColumnD

Comment: @fireholster how did you get on?

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for checking in. For this particular case, I went ahead and streamlined my view query to stop sending those duplicates. your suggestion did worked through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the window function `row_number()` to accomplish this. So its partitioning by the columns you want to compare, and ordering by the preferred result

```
declare @Test table (Col1 varchar(2), Col2 varchar(2), Col3 varchar(2), Col4 varchar(2));

insert into @Test (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
values
('AA','BA','CA','Y'),
('AA','BA','CA','N'),
('BB','CD','DA','N'),
('CC','GH','IJ','Y');

select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
from (
  select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
    , row_number() over (partition by Col1, Col2, Col3 order by Col4 desc) RowNum
  from @Test
) X
-- To understand how this works comment out the following line
where RowNum = 1;
```

Returns:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
AA      BA      CA      Y
BB      CD      DA      N
CC      GH      IJ      Y
```

Note the data displayed as formatted text, and the DDL/DML statements to setup test data.

Comment: Thanks Dale. Let me first understand it. will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your real data looks like, but here is a simple approach:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    ColumnA VARCHAR(2), ColumnB VARCHAR(2), ColumnC VARCHAR(2), ColumnD VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @Table ( ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD ) VALUES
    ( 'AA', 'BA', 'CA', 'Y' ), ( 'AA', 'BA', 'CA', 'N' ), ( 'BB', 'CD', 'DA', 'N' ), ( 'CC', 'GH', 'IJ', 'Y' );

SELECT
    ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, MAX ( ColumnD ) AS ColumnD
FROM @Table AS t1
GROUP BY
    ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC;
```

Returns

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| AA      | BA      | CA      | Y       |
| BB      | CD      | DA      | N       |
| CC      | GH      | IJ      | Y       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this.

```
select
  *
from
  Table
where
  (
    ColumnD = 'Y'
    or (
      ColumnD = 'N'
      and Concat(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) not in (
        select
          Concat(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
        from
          Table
        where
          ColumnD = 'Y'
      )
    )
  )
```